# Dbunit upgrade give unique constraint violation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb, dbunit

I am attempting to my upgrade hibernate libraries for some legacy code and am suddenly getting a unique constraint violation in my unit tests:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10344 table: GROUP
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.dbunit.database.statement.SimplePreparedStatement.addBatch(SimplePreparedStatement.java:67)
    at org.dbunit.database.statement.AutomaticPreparedBatchStatement.addBatch(AutomaticPreparedBatchStatement.java:57)
    at org.dbunit.operation.AbstractBatchOperation.execute(AbstractBatchOperation.java:178)
    at gov.treas.fms.shared.test.spring.AbstractTransactionalSpringTest.loadDataset(AbstractTransactionalSpringTest.java:551)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation; SYS_PK_10344 table: GROUP
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Constraint.getException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.index.IndexAVLMemory.insert(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.persist.RowStoreAVL.indexRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.TransactionManager2PL.addInsertAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.addInsertAction(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Table.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.insertSingleRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementInsert.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 27 more
```

New library versions

hibernate-commons-annotations: 4.0.5.Final
hibernate-entitymanager: 4.3.10.Final
hibernate-core: 4.3.10.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api: 1.0.0.Final
hsqldb 2.3.4
dbunit: 2.1

Old library versions

hibernate-annotations: 3.4.0.GA
hibernate-commons-annotations: 3.1.0.GA
hibernate-entitymanager: 3.4.0.GA
hibernate-core: 3.3.0.SP1
hsqldb: 1.8.0.7
dbunit: 2.1

The entities look like this:

```
@AttributeOverrides(
    {
            @AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "group_id"))
    }
)
public class Group extends AbstractIdentity {
    private String description;

    private String name;

    //getters and setters

}


public abstract class AbstractIdentity {

    private long id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "IdSequenceGenerator")
    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }       
}
```

The dbunit data set looks like this:

```
<dataset>
    <group group_id="100"
        description="Group description"
        name="Group name"/>
</dataset>
```

It is loaded like this:

```
IDataSet dataset = constructDbUnitDataset(datasetResourcePath);
DatabaseOperation.INSERT.execute(connection, dataset);
```

The DataOperation.INSERT line is where I'm getting the exception.

Note that if I run one unit test, it passes. If I run more than one, I get the above exception.

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Compare the DDL gen from prior Hibernate version with the new, you may find different constraints.

Sometimes a prior test leaves data in the DB; run two tests that show the problem and see the data after the first one, ensuring all tables are cleaned up.